# In spotfire, IronPython script: No Module named Selenium

Tags: automation, ironpython, spotfire

I am newly exploring to write IronPython script in spotfire, i started to write the code with "from selenium import webdriver" and executed the code, i am getting the ImportError: No Module named selenium.

As a prior step before executing of this code, i installed package "selenium" from python package management. My question why i am getting this error, is there any pre-requisite which i need to do? Is there anything that i need to set in document property before writing the code?

Attached the screenshot of the error. Please help me to resolve this error.

Thanks,
Ganesh K

[[Packeges installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPkTH.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZodVV.jpg)